# How do I make Arpwatch only send new activity/new station emails?

Tags: pfsense, arp

I had set up Arpwatch on my office's pfSense 2.4.3 gateway. Ever since I had done that, I started getting a whole lot of emails - most of them very useful, while some are less useful.

I wonder if there is any way of restricting Arpwatch's reports only to **new activity/new station**, without the **flip flop** reports (which stand for 90% of all emails)?

Sure, I could use email filters as a last resort, but those emails are supposed to go to a whole team and not just me.